# Amazon S3: Can we download image in base64 encode string

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, amazon-s3, base64

I know in Amazon S3 we can upload images in base64 string format. Is there a functionality that we can download the image from amazon in base64 format rather than URL of the amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for [GetObject](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPGetObject.html)?